# Is it possible for the item_id of a Plaid Item to change?

Tags: plaid

I notice that in Plaid you query an item based on its access_token. The item also has an item_id which I understand is a unique identifier. I know that it is possible to have two distinct items referencing the same credentials at an institution if a user links to it twice. My question is this: Is there any chance that /item/get for a specific access_token would return a different item_id than it did in the past? If it is possible, what should we do if it happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `item_id` is immutable. It will not change for a given `access_token`.